# How to retrieve multidimensional array using json in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that I want to retrieve using JSON in android. I have the following JSON Structure for this :

```
  [
      [
        {
          "name": "Banking",
          "data": [
            {
              "vendor_name": "SBI",
              "vendor_id": "1"
            },
            {
              "vendor_name": "ICICI",
              "vendor_id": "2"
            },
            {
              "vendor_name": "BOB",
              "vendor_id": "3"
            }
          ],
          "count": 4
        }
     ]
 ]
```

I want to get `"name"`,`vendor_name`,`vendor_id` in my Strings in android. But I am not getting idea how to do this. Please let me know how to retrieve this.

Comment: tried...after that I post here...!!! :(

Comment: you want to convert your json array to 2d array for example ya?

Comment: There are many json parsers in java like gson, jackson etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804108/getting-multidimensional-array-from-jsonarrayphp-to-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
     try {
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(YourString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.v("Error in Parser", " " + e);
        }
    try{

     String name=jsonObj.getString("name"); 
            Data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < Data.length(); i++) {       
                        JSONObject jsonObj2 = Data.getJSONObject(j);   
                        String vName = jsonObj2.getString("vendor_name");
                        String vId=jsonObj2.getString("vendor_id");     
                }
}catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

Comment: try above code you will get the desired output!!!

Comment: dont just let them copy and paste the code, at least let them know what is happening in your snippet

Comment: I wish you explained what the Data class is since there are multiple packages the Android studio asks you to import. While I appreciate your answer, it would have been more helpful if you included some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
try{
   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("[[{\"name\":\"Banking\",\"data\":[{\"vendor_name\":\"SBI\",\"vendor_id\":\"1\"},{\"vendor_name\":\"ICICI\",\"vendor_id\":\"2\"},{\"vendor_name\":\"BOB\",\"vendor_id\":\"3\"}],\"count\":4}]]");
   HashMap<String,Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> dataList =  new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

   responseMap.put("name",jsonArray.getJSONArray(0).getJSONObject(0).getString("name"));
   for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.getJSONArray(0).getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("data").length();i++){
       HashMap<String,String> dataRow = new HashMap<String, String>();
       dataRow.put("vendor_name",jsonArray.getJSONArray(0).getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i).getString("vendor_name"));
       dataRow.put("vendor_id",jsonArray.getJSONArray(0).getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i).getString("vendor_id"));
       dataList.add(dataRow);
   }
   responseMap.put("data",dataList);
   responseMap.put("count",jsonArray.getJSONArray(0).getJSONObject(0).getString("count"));

   System.out.print("name : "+responseMap.get("name").toString());
   ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>)responseMap.get("data");
   for (HashMap<String,String> row : list){
        System.out.print("vendor_name : "+row.get("count"));
        System.out.print("vendor_id : "+row.get("count"));
   }
   System.out.print("count : "+responseMap.get("count").toString());
}catch (Throwable e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Just friendly suggestion, do not you think there is a need to explain at least very simple sample so novice op can learn ?

Comment: @KickButtowski,Dear here i not put any unfamiliar or not understable code so any one know json easily understood whatever i have done here  and last thanks for you suggestion

Comment: And what About those of use who don't ...