# Getting NetworkOnMainThread error when trying to do HTTP Post

Tags: java, android, http-post, networkonmainthread

Hi i am trying to do a simple HTTP post to a PHP based server which accepts a POST data $_POST['username'].

```
public void sendMessage(View view){

    String result = "";

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);

    Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "Attempting to open second activity",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
    ).show();

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username","ghost"));

    InputStream is = null;

    // ATTEMPT HTTP POST
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/getuserbyuname");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection (Reason: " + e.toString() + " )");
    }
```

The server will then return a JSON formatted message like this:

```
{"response":"404"}
```

I am having a problem with android.os.NetworkOnMainThread. I am aware that this is due to my routine is trying to do Network related operation from within the main UI Thread.

I did try this:

```
public class AccountConnector extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, Long>{

@Override
protected Long doInBackground(String... params)
{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username","bond"));

    InputStream is = null;

    // ATTEMPT HTTP POST
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/getuserbyuname");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection (Reason: " + e.toString() + " )");
    }
    return null;
}
```

... rest of code is omitted ...

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you want your network I/O to run in the main thread?

Comment: use AsynchTask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html )     Example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057712/pass-arraylist-bean-from-android-to-webservice-php/17058208#17058208

Comment: @mthmulders basically to check whether queried uname exists in DB or not.

Comment: @KaranMavadhiya looking into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add this..

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
             .permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

put this in manifest file

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way of solving this is to use [Android AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidTools/article.html) for network access.

The lazy way of handling this is to turn the check of:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: i did look into your reference. However, quoting from the article this is what it says "StrictMode should only be used during development and not in your live application."